# Separated sets Theorem

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of a topological  space $X$. If $A$ and $B$ are both open or both closed, then the sets $A -B$ and $B-A$ are separated sets.

My thinking is :

Suppose that $A-B$ and $B-A$ are not separated sets. Let $x\in (A-B)$, then $x\in (B-A)$ since $(A-B)\cap (B-A) \neq \emptyset$. Then $x\in A, x\not\in B$ for $x\in (A-B)$ and $x\not\in A$,$x\in B$ for $x\in (B-A)$, which is contradiction. So, $(A-B)\cap$$（B-A) =$ $\emptyset$.

but how can I prove that $(A-B)\cap \overline{(B-A)}$ =  $(A-B)\cap (B-A)$.

Comment: What definition of "separated" are we using?

Answer (score 1):

What you managed to prove is that the sets $A-B$ and $B-A$ are *disjoint*. This is not a topological property it belongs to elementary set theory.

In order to prove $(A-B)\cap\overline{(B-A)}=\emptyset$, note that we have two cases: (1) both $A$ and $B$ are  open and (b) both are closed. I'll show you how to solve the former, the latter should be similar.

Note that $A-B\subseteq A$ and that $A\cap(B-A)=\emptyset$. From this follows that $A-B\cap \mathscr{C}A=\emptyset$ and $B-A\subseteq\mathscr{C}A$. Since $\mathscr{C}A$ is closed, $\overline{B-A}\subseteq \mathscr{C}A$. Since $A-B\cap\mathscr{C}A=\emptyset$, *a fortiori*, $A-B\cap \overline{(B-A)}=\emptyset$.